How can I manage the issue of excessive gas estimation in MetaMask when deploying a dapp contract on my WASM+EVM chain and calling its functions?
i am trying to deploy a dapp contract on my WASM + EVM based substrate chain but while calling the contract functions it gives me high gas estimation, how can i handle this issue?
